# Does anybody know of any good PHP Codeigniter auto form generators?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I have googled this but wanted to see what the general concensus was on stack overflow.

Does anybody know of any good PHP Codeigniter auto form generators?

I want to be able to create some forms based on a mysql database table.

Does anybody know any good ones?

Comment: you could try http://formigniter.org/. I dont know how flexible it si.  Get yourself a good IDE with code completion snippets to help with repetative tasks suchs as these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following sparks - they all work well - just personal perference

http://getsparks.org/packages/autoform/versions/HEAD/show

http://getsparks.org/packages/formgenlib/versions/HEAD/show

http://getsparks.org/packages/FluentForm/versions/HEAD/show

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some CRUD sort of functionalty - have a look at this 
http://www.grocerycrud.com/

http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/the-simplest-example

> Only one line of code... Even if you are bored to write the set_table
>   function , the library searchs if the function name exists as a table
>   name
>
> ```
> function offices()
> {
>     $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();
>
>     $this->_example_output($output);
> }
> ```
>
> And your CRUD is ready :-)
>
> In this example I set the table name (offices) and I get the default
>   Crud with add-edit and delete (create-update-delete). All the views
>   are ready and you don't need anything else.